# Convert to CST Using Joda API

Tags: timezone, jodatime

Any one know how to convert `UTC` time to `CST` time using `joda date time api` ?
My code is something like this.

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID("CST");
DateTime mstTime = utcDateTime.toDateTime(zone);
```

Api says 'The datetime zone id `CST` is not recognised'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short time-zone ids like "CST" are unclear and ambiguous, so they are not supported. Use a longer form, like "America/New_York".

Answer (score 2):

Some of the three-letter time zones (EST and MST, for example) are included in the default time zone database used by Joda. Others (CST and PST, for example) are not. (See http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html for more details.)

The time zone IDs supported by Joda can be obtained by calling `org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.getAvailableIDs()`, and that set does **differ** from those returned by `java.util.TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "**CST6CDT**" format of joda time.