# Joda Time DateTimeFormatter handling CST

Tags: java, parsing, timezone, jodatime

I'm trying to parse some date strings which I receive in the following format using Joda Time

```
Sat, 08 Dec 2012 00:00:00 CST
```

Looking at the documentation, [DateTimeFormat](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) won't handle the parsing of this due to the time zone name been ambiguous.  Given I have no control over the data strings I'm receiving, what is the best/simplest way to parse this into DateTime object?

Edit: I know this is Central Time Zone (North America) rather than one of the other possible time zones CST may refer too.

Comment: [See this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635704/convert-to-cst-using-joda-api) which has been answered by the main contributor to joda time. So I think you have no choice but replace "CST" with the adequate long form time zone name.

Comment: Perfect, that does seem to be a very simple way to solve my problem.  I just had to add support for the pattern "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZ" as well as "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z" (the rest of the dates I was using hat the time stamp format with +TTTT as the time zone)